# cannot add AdMob to my app - null object reference

Tags: android

i am trying to add the google admob to my android application and for some reason its gave me a error and the aplication is cashing.
hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

i am getting this logcat

```
04-27 18:29:04.361    3422-3422/com.math E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.math, PID: 3422
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.math/com.math.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

and i dont know why is this happend,
this is my code:

public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
private AdView mAdView;
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private  ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private float lastX;
/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest.Builder request = new AdRequest.Builder();
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(request.build());
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastX = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();

            // Handling left to right screen swap.
            if (lastX < currentX) {

                // If there aren't any other children, just break.
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                    break;

                // Next screen comes in from left.
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
                // Current screen goes out from right.
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

                // Display next screen.
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }

            // Handling right to left screen swap.
            if (lastX > currentX) {

                // If there is a child (to the left), kust break.
                if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                    break;

                // Next screen comes in from right.
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
                // Current screen goes out from left.
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

                // Display previous screen.
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welcome, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

/** Called when returning to the activity */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Welcome$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/windows_pc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the ALL of Activity code. Post the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity layout (`activity_my.xml`) does not contain an `AdView` view with id `ad_view`. That view is located in your fragment, which is not yet loaded when you start an activity.

You have 2 choices:

- Transfer `AdView` code to your fragment's callback methods, e.g. `onCreateView`
- Add the AdView directly to your activity's layout like this:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          ads:adSize="BANNER"
          ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
      </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

For more information see Android's [quick start guide for AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start).

Comment: i did it and this isnt fix that

Comment: @yuval post your activity layout.

Comment: posted in the post above

Comment: @yuval so are you sure that this `findViewById(R.id.adView)` returns `null`?